# Setting up phpMyAdmin on a 1&1 Managed Dedicated Server

Tags: mysql, socket, phpmyadmin, 1and1

I'm trying to set up phpMyAdmin on my Managed Dedi Server from 1&1 so that I don't have to log into my 1&1 Account to access the databases / so that my developers don't have to know my account details.

The Host Name I use to connect to databases using Wordpress etc is "localhost:/tmp/mysql5.sock", how would I use this in phpMyAdmin Setup as just using this as the host name doesn't work. It comes up with the error "Couldn't log into mySQL Database" even though I am using the correct Username and Password.

Please see the screenshots below of my setup.

[phpMyAdmin Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPkmC.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try just localhost, or 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Did you try in hostname to put localhost, in socket /tmp/mysql5.sock ?

Comment: Hi, yes, I have tried using localhost, 127.0.0.1 and localhost:/tmp/mysql5.sock for the hostname and have also tried the socket idea as well... I'm co confused as to why this isn't working.

Comment: phpmyadmin is run by the apache(or equivalent, the user who's running the webserver) user, so this user should be able to access the socket file. Did you check the socket + socket dir permissions/user/group ?

Comment: I left it a day and it started working... Maybe the server guys tweaked a setting somewhere on the server.. Who knows!